# Get neighbor block that exists in a different chunk

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, procedural-generation, voxel

My question is very similar to this, but I couldn't quite work it out, as the math needs to be a little different: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/65800/when-storing-voxels-in-chunks-how-do-i-access-them-at-the-world-level

I am trying to remove some faces of blocks.  I'm having trouble working out how to get a block if it's outside the current chunk.

I have a Chunk class that keeps track of its own blocks.  For testing, my chunks are 2 x 2, which holds 4 blocks each, all solid.

```
class Chunk {

    private Blocks[,,] blocks;

    public Vector3 position;

    public Chunk(Vector3 world_pos){
        position = world_position;

        // Loops for populating blocks array...
        ...

        // Create mesh

        for(...){
            for(...){
                for(...){
                    Block block = GetBlock(x, y, z + 1); // Chance of this block being outside of this chunk
                }
            }
        }       
    }

    public Block GetBlock(int x, int y, int z){
        ...

        // If block is not in this chunk, use global GetBlock instead
    }

}
```

I have a method inside the chunk called "getBlock" that attempts to get a block based on the x, y, and z position.  If the indexes are out of range, I then call a global "getBlock" which attempts to find the chunk and the block inside of it.  This is where I am struggling.

This is my "getChunk" method (not my code, found in a tutorial), which seems to be fine.

```
public Chunk getChunk(int x, int y, int z){
    float s = CHUNK_SIZE;
    float d = CHUNK_DEPTH;

    int posx = Mathf.FloorToInt(x / s) * CHUNK_SIZE;
    int posy = Mathf.FloorToInt(y / d) * CHUNK_DEPTH;
    int posz = Mathf.FloorToInt(z / s) * CHUNK_SIZE;

    Chunk chunk = null;

    this.chunks.TryGetValue(new Vector3(posx, posy, posz), out chunk);

    return chunk;
}
```

Here is my global "getBlock".

```
public Block getBlock(int x, int y, int z){
    Chunk chunk = this.getChunk(x, y, z);
    Block block;

    if(chunk == null){
        block = Block_Types.AIR;
    } else {

        // Need to work out the block position I want here

        int posx = x;
        int posy = y;
        int posz = z;

        block = chunk.getBlock(posx, posy, posz);

    }

    return block;
}
```

Here is a picture if it helps:

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSDEx.png)

Thanks

Comment: This would really benefit from digging into Minecraft's chunk code.  Essentially you need to modify the xyz values from world coordinates into chunk coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Divide the global position by `CHUNK_SIZE` and take the remainder as the chunk's local position.
You can use modulo (%) operator for that:

```
x = posx % CHUNK_SIZE;
y = posy % CHUNK_SIZE;
z = posz % CHUNK_SIZE;
```

e.g.

```
0 / 2 = 0; r = 0;
1 / 2 = 0; r = 1;
2 / 2 = 1; r = 0;
3 / 2 = 1; r = 1;
4 = 2 = 2; r = 0;
5 = 2 = 2; r = 1;
```

Comment: My problem is getting the world block position I think.  If I do getBlock(0, 0, 0 - 1), and a chunk does exist, how do I convert that to (0, 0, 3).

Comment: @JacketPotatoeFan I don't see a problem here. When you pass your world coordinates `(x,y,z)` to the `getBlock` function you find the corresponding chunk. At this point, you either have the chunk which contains your block, or the chunk is null – implying you're out of bounds. You then do what I said in my answer which converts world coordinates to local coordinates. Now you have a direct reference to the block you were interested in.

Comment: My block coordinates are not world coordinates.  I need to convert to world coords, then convert to local coords for the chunk I am checking.  Am basically trying to remove the big plus inside the 4 chunks http://i.imgur.com/cbwJiRi.png

Comment: @JacketPotatoeFan I'm sorry, but then what is the initial space of your block coordinates that you're working with? Anything other than world coordinates seems strange to me.